Isomorphism of vector bundle defined by transition function
Let $X$ be a riemann surface (1-dim complex manifold), and let $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ be an open cover of $X$. Let $g_{ij},g'_{ij}: U_i\cap U_j\to \mathcal{O}^*$(holomorphic non-zero functions on $U_i\cap U_j$) be two family of transition functions defining two line bundles $L,L'$. Suppose that there exists functions $\varphi_i:U_i\to \mathcal{O}^*$ for all $i\in I$, such that $g'_{ij}=\varphi_i\varphi_j^{-1}g_{ij}$. Then how should I prove $L$ and $L'$ are isomorphic?

Did you write down what it means for the line bundles to be isomorphic? You're going to need a commutative diagram here.

@TedShifrin I don't know how to type diagram here, but it's just the standard definition. Two line bundles are isomorphic, if there exists a bundle homomorphism with inverse (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle#Vector_bundle_morphisms)

OK, now interpret the isomorphism in terms of trivializations of the respective bundles. That’s where the $\varphi_i$ come from.

We denote the trivialization of $L$ over $U_i$ by $f_i$, i.e. $f_i:\,L|_{U_i}\to U_i\times\mathbb{C}$ is a homeomorphism. Similarly we define $f_i'$ for $L'$. Then $g_{ij}$ is induced by $f_if_j^{-1}$ restricting to $U_i\cap U_j$. We define a map $\bar{\varphi}_i:\,U_i\times\mathbb{C}\to U_i\times\mathbb{C}$ by
$$\bar{\varphi}_i(x,z):=(x,\varphi(x)z).$$
Consider the following composition of maps:
$$L|_{U_i}\xrightarrow{\text{$f_i$}}U_i\times\mathbb{C}\xrightarrow{\text{$\bar{\varphi}_i$}}U_i\times\mathbb{C}\xrightarrow{\text{$(f_i')^{-1}$}}L'|_{U_i}.$$
We denote this map by $\Phi_i$. The condition $g_{ij}'=\varphi_i\varphi_j^{-1}g_{ij}$ yields $\Phi_i$ and $\Phi_j$ coincides on $L|_{U_i\cap U_j}$. So put all the $\Phi_i$ together we obtain a global bundle morphism $\Phi:\,L\to L'$, which is the isomorphism we need.
